# Is it grammatically correct to omit the words "yes" or "no" when replying to questions?

Tags: grammar

Is it natural to use only auxilliary verbs when answering questions. For example:

> Person A: Does he live in the house?
>
> Person B: He **does**.
>
> Person A: Has he won the game?
>
> Person B: He **has**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it grammatically correct to omit the words “yes” or “no” when replying to questions?
>
> It is.

You see what I did there? Yes, if you make a statement that repeats back the question or some key words of the question as a statement, it is common to omit any "yes" or "no".

If it's a simple question, sometimes just "yes" or "no" is all you need to answer it.

> Do you agree?
>
> Yes.

Sometimes we feed back the question instead of saying "yes" or "no".

> Do you agree?
>
> I agree.

Sometimes we do both.

> Do you agree?
>
> Yes, I agree.

Generally will do both if that helps for clarity. This can be especially useful if the question is long and wordy. Especially if it includes multiple options so that a simple "yes" or "no" might make it unclear what you are agreeing (or disagreeing) with.

> Will you go to Chicago tomorrow, or are you considering delaying your trip?

If you just said "yes", it wouldn't be clear whether you meant, "Yes,  I am going tomorrow", or "yes, I am delaying my trip".

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it's natural to omit yes or no. Each case is different and should be judged independently.